# Prove that f is constant using Cauchy-Riemann eq

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives

If $|f(z)|>1$  and $f$ analytic prove $f$ is constant. I can solve it prety easy with liouvile's theorem . $$g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)} $$ is analytic since $f(z)$ never zero  and$|g(z)|<1$ thus $g(z)$ constant thus $f(z)=\frac{1}{c}$ right? How to prove that with C.R equations. I tried taking $$|f|=u^2+v^2$$ and i know this function is analytic with imaginary part zero. but i get $uu_x=-vv_x$ if i use the C.R equations on that function . and i dont know how to use this fact even knowing that $u_x=v_y$  from C.R  of the initial f.

Answer (score 2):

The Cauchy–Riemann equations are a local characterisation of complex-differentiable functions. The condition you have is global, so any link to the Cauchy–Riemann equations will only be through other global results (something like the Cauchy integral formula, for example.) One could note that the real and imaginary parts of $1/f$ are harmonic as a consequence of the Cauchy–Riemann equations and then use Liouville's theorem for harmonic functions (obligatory mention of [Nelson's proof](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1961-012-06/S0002-9939-1961-0259149-4/S0002-9939-1961-0259149-4.pdf)), but when you already have the complex version, why bother?